# ORA- 00922 error in table creation in the apex 5

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to create a table in apex5 with reference having foreign key from another table and that foreign key column is populated. But to create is returning the error ORA- 00922: missing or invalid option, already checked and not noticed any error naming what can is going wrong? The following code:

```
CREATE TABLE  "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA" 
(   "COD" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"COD_SISTEMA" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"NOME" VARCHAR2(55), 
"ARQUIVO_IMAGEM" BLOB, 
"MIMETYPE" VARCHAR2(255), 
"FILENAME" VARCHAR2(400), 
"IMG_LAST_UPDATE" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, 
"UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(55), 
"TEXTO_DESCRICAO" VARCHAR2(55), 
"LINK" VARCHAR2(2000), 
"NUM_ORDEM" NUMBER(6,0), 
CONSTRAINT "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEM_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("COD") USING INDEX ENABLE)
/
ALTER TABLE  "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA" ADD CONSTRAINT "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("COD_SISTEMA")
REFERENCES  "APEX_SISTEMA" ("COD") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
/


CREATE INDEX  "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA_I2" ON  "IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA" ("COD_SISTEMA")
/

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "BI_IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA" before insert or update on IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA               
for each row  
begin   
    if :new.COD is null then
        select to_number(sys_guid(),'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') into :new.cod from dual;
    end if; 
    if inserting then
        :new.img_last_update := localtimestamp;
        :new.updated_by := nvl(wwv_flow.g_user,user);
    elsif updating and :new.filename is not null and nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(:new.arquivo_imagem),0) > 15728640 then raise_application_error(-20000, 'O tamanho do arquivo enviado foi maior do que 15MB . Faça o upload de um arquivo de tamanho menor.');
    end if;
    if (inserting or updating) and :new.filename is not null and nvl(:new.mimetype,'NULL') not like 'image%' then
   raise_application_error(-20000, 'O arquivo enviado não é uma imagem. Faça o upload de um arquivo de imagem.');
    end if;
    if inserting or updating then
        :new.img_last_update := localtimestamp;
        :new.updated_by := nvl(wwv_flow.g_user,user);
    end if;
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_IMAGEM_ICONE_SISTEMA" ENABLE
/
```

Comment: Does the trigger need to support editioning or not?  It compiles without the `EDITIONABLE` keyword, but is there a reason it's there?

Comment: This trigger is for validations of some table columns, can even be inserted later. I realized that when I try to compile only the create table command, it creates the table, but also enter the alter table command he gives this error.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I wasn't clear.  What I meant to ask was is there a reason the trigger includes the `EDITIONABLE` keyword?  Also, I couldn't reproduce an error just with the `ALTER TABLE` statement: that worked fine for me.

Comment: Hello Luke, I managed to solve. The problem is that the apex have to compile by parts , it does not compile all at once. Thus creating the table compiled after including the commands one by one. But when compiling the trigger, also occurred the same mistake, and you were right, the problem is the EDITIONABLE keyword. Without it, the trigger compiled without causing errors. Thank you for your help.